# AutocompleteTextView with 1000 entries in Arraylist not working

Tags: android, performance, large-data, autocompletetextview

Working on an android app, which has a form with autocompletetextview with custom adapter, for which we have arraylist of around 1k entries. But with 1K data it is not working. With around 400 entries, it is working but filtering is slow.
What can be done to handle this kind of large data set?

following is the code snippet for filtering:

```
     @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (constraint != null) {
            suggestions.clear();

            for (ToMeet toMeet : tempItems) {
                if (toMeet.getNm().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()) ||
                        (toMeet.getAptNo() != null && toMeet.getAptNo().toLowerCase().toLowerCase().
                                contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))) {

                    suggestions.add(toMeet);
                }
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = suggestions;
            filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
            return filterResults;
        } else {
            return new FilterResults();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            ArrayList<ToMeet> filteredList = (ArrayList<ToMeet>) ((ArrayList<ToMeet>) results.values).clone();
            clear();
            for (ToMeet toMeet : filteredList) {
                add(toMeet);

            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `publishResults` method you are calling the `Adapter` `add` method for each result.  Every time the add method is called, the list is notified that it has been changed.

This could cause the slow behavior you are seeing.

Instead use the `Adapter` `addAll` method.  The notification that the dataset has changed should be called for you by `addAll` unless you changed the default behavior with the `setNotifyOnChange`

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    clear();
    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
        addAll(results)
    }
}
```

You could also optimize your `performFiltering` method to use a [trie](https://github.com/arunkumar9t2/trie) datastructure, but I don't think you should need to for 1,000 items.

Comment: Thanks, will check this and let you know.